# Error while running the command npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, enoent

I'm trying to run a react code and used the command **npm install** and error(s) pop up:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\Test/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\Test\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!      C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-29T05_40_15_503Z-debug-0.log
```

Help me resolve these errors, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `npm` can't find the `package.json` file.

Normally, this is a very simple problem that can be fixed easily.

---

**1. Not in the directory of `package.json`**

If you already have the `package.json` file, then you need to make sure that you are in the directory in which the file is in.

To see if the file is in your directory, run the `dir` command.

```
$ dir
```

If you aren't in the directory in which `package.json` is in, then navigate to that directory.

---

**2. Creation of `package.json`**

Another issue that can occur is that you haven't yet created a `package.json` file.

To do this, run the following command.

```
$ npm init
```

However, if you don't want to answer the questions from running that command, run the following.

```
$ npm init -y
```

This will initialise the `package.json` file in your directory.

---

**Edit:** If you try to run `npm install`, and you get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE - unable to resolve dependency tree
```

That means that you have a dependency conflict. To fix this issue, run  the command with the following flag.

```
$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

This will resolve any incompatible packages (e.g. one package needs a lower version then what you currently have).

---

After you have done either of these solutions, then running the command below should work successfully.

```
$ npm install
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but it raised another error, npm ERR! code ERESOLVE - unable to resolve dependency tree.

Comment: See my edit. You need to run the `npm install` command with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag. See my edit for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the dependence by force.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps --force
```

Go to the terminal and try this command.

Answer (score 0):

You need a package.json file in yor project you can run this command :
`npm init --yes`